# Some windows' content on external screen displays all black when screen is connected via HDMI but not VGA

Tags: macos, hdmi, external-display, apple-mail

I have replaced the VGA cable as well as the display adaptor between my MacBook (Fall 2011 with HighSierra v. 10.13.6) and my Samsung external screen with an HDMI one. After that, some of my emails show up almost completely black on that screen, but if I move the window to the internal screen, the problem disappears.  Only some emails show up wrong, others work as expected. I have not seen the same problems in other applications besides Mail.

I do not have this issue when the screen is connected with a VGA cable. There are no general problems with colours on the internal or external display.

What I have tried so far:

- Tried a different HDMI cable (completely new one)
- Unplugged and plugged in again the Display Port - HDMI adaptor
- Restarted Mail
- Rebooted
- Checked for Apple updates

Email displayed on external screen using HDMI:
[image: Email displayed on external screen using HDMI]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the second image is what the email looks like when properly displayed (it would be helpful to label that image for all the English-only readers on this English-only site).  This is a strange problem.  If the mode of connection (HDMI vs. VGA) is going to affect what you see, it's typically all or nothing, not specific content in selected windows.  Can you think of any other information that might have diagnostic value (e.g., is the problem limited to this one application)?

Comment: What happens if you position the window half on one display and half on the second?

Comment: It's curiously relevant that you're able to capture a *screen shot* of this phenomenon. That demonstrates the computer is generating the black area of the screen vs. the display simply not showing that portion of the screen...

Comment: fixer1234, you're right about that. The two screenshots are from the internal and external screen with the same content.

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator, it's not really possible to leave a window half-on-half on mac. The minor part of the window will not be shown. However, when I move the window, it shows the content correctly while dragging, but once I release the mouse button the content turns black.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is a bug in the macOS Mail application. I have only seen this in Mail.

Comment: What happens if you change the resolution of the problem display? Does that fix it?

Comment: No, changing the resolution does not help. However, I just found this page that describes the exact same problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8110030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with conversations in Mail. What happened was that single emails are displayed correctly, but once you hit reply or forward and the mail becomes part of a *conversation*, it displays wrong.

The solution is to do a screen calibration of the external screen. You'll find calibration under Settings > Screen:

[image: Calibrating screen in macOS]

Further info can be found here: 
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mail-conversation-view-broken-showing-black-in-mac-os-high-sierra.2074912/